# Laravel-mix no build notification

Tags: linux, laravel, vue.js, notifications, laravel-mix

I'm using Vue.js and Laravel-Mix, when I save the project I don't receive any notification like this :

[image: Build Successful notification]

I'm running `npm run watch`. My console doesn't display any errors / warnings when I compile.

[image]

I already checked the `webpack.mix.js` for `mix.disableSuccessNotifications();`
 and I don't have that on my file, my notifications are working on my OS. I'm using Linux Mint.

I have this on `package.json`:

```
"watch": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --watch-poll --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```

- npm : 3.10.10
- node : 6.14.1

I have a friend that has the same project and he gets the notification "Build Successful"

Comment: Are you running the npm commands on your local machine or are you using homestead?

Comment: local machine @GoogleMac

Comment: Can you look at this? https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/967

Comment: How can I make sure my OS isn't blocking the notifications?

Comment: Also, what version of npm are you using?

Comment: @GoogleMac npm : 3.10.10 | node : 6.14.1 (I have a friend that has the same versions and gets the notifications, same project aswell)

Comment: I have the same issue as described above. I have libnotify installed, and the notifications appear if I run "npm run dev", just not on "npm run watch"

To be clear, my "npm run watch" includes --watch-poll. Without this, the notification appears after the initial build, but it doesn't pick up any changed files, so I need --watch-poll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you have `notify-send` installed.

follow this if you have any issues
https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2177

Answer (score 7):

Using Linux Mint 18.3, I needed to install the `libnotify-bin` package to have notifications displayed. Probably works on Ubuntu as well:

`sudo apt-get install -y libnotify-bin`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it actually solves the problem (the `libnotify-bin` library must be installed) and tells you how to solve it. The currently selected answer only provides a vague debugging solution and is not by any means a solution to the posed problem. This answer on the other hand actually solves the problem.
The `libnotify-bin` is the cli binary that connects to `notify-osd` package which is Ubuntu's built in notifications. So you might need to install `notify-osd` as well if it isn't already installed. 
See: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1411620

Answer (score 4):

I know this is too old to answer but I fixed it by just turning the notification on in my settings.

1. Go to settings.
2. Search for notification.
3. Scroll down until you see terminal-notifier.
4. Click, and turn it on.
5. Run `npm run watch` again.

P.S. I'm using macOS Catalina

Comment: This worked, thanks. But why did it get turned off? Was working fine for ages. Only thing I did recently was a `brew update`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on macOS High Sierra.  Turns out the OS automatically stopped notifications when I had an external monitor plugged in.  The right-most icon on the task-bar on top allows you to disable this.   Presumably it's so you don't get interruptions when doing presentations.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that almost 70% of windows OS we disable notifications which later hides the successful compilation of Laravel Mix.

If you go to your computer on windows 10 that is

1.SETTINGS, 
2.NOTIFICATIONS AND ACTIONS, 
3.NOTIFICATIONS FROM OTHER SENDERS and switch it to on

This enables or it starts showing again.

Answer (score 0):

HLO FRIENDS,

I FIND THE EXACT SOLUTION OF THIS QUESTION.

1).  First of all check your notification in setting check all apps are able to sent a notification.

2).  In your laravel project setup follow the given file path:-
**node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\Notifications.js**

```js
const { Component } = require('./Component');

module.exports = class Notifications extends Component {
    passive = true;

    /**
     * webpack plugins to be appended to the master config.
     */
    webpackPlugins() {
        if (!this.enabled) {
            return [];
        }

        if (process.env.DISABLE_NOTIFICATIONS === '1') {
            return [];
        }

        const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

        return [
            new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
                appID: 'Laravel Mix',
                title: 'Laravel Mix',
                alwaysNotify: this.context.config.notifications.onSuccess,
                timeout: false,
                hint: process.platform === 'linux' ? 'int:transient:1' : undefined,
                contentImage: this.context.paths.root(
                    'node_modules/laravel-mix/icons/laravel.png'
                )
            })
        ];
    }

    get enabled() {
        const { notifications } = this.context.config;

        return notifications && (notifications.onSuccess || notifications.onFailure);
    }
};
```

Now, we find a line of code in the given program **appID: 'Laravel Mix',** now replace this line with **appID: 'Laravel Mix Plus',**
=> save the file and run the node command again

> npm run watch

now you are able to see the notification from **laravel Mix Plus**.
your notification problem is solved.

Thanks

Comment: Hope you find this solution helpful.