# npm run watch compililing successfully but laravel Mix build successful notification is not showing

Tags: windows, laravel, vue.js, ecmascript-6

When I run `npm run watch` it is compiled successfully, and changes are updated automatically, but Laravel Mix successful build notification is not displaying. Please suggest to me how I can activate this notification? 
My operating system is Windows.

[image]

Comment: i have seen similar question but their operation system is different . so i asked again.

Comment: I'm on osx, if I'm ssh'ed into VM and run npm run watch there, it doesn't show the notification, if I run directly on my machine, it shows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel-mix no build notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755414/laravel-mix-no-build-notification)

Comment: There's answer is only for Linux not for windows. I have tried this and mention about this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on Windows 10 by going to Settings > Background apps > Let apps run in the background turned on. Then I selected from which apps can run to include **Messaging**.